# The layout is changed by setAlpha method, but the view hierarchy I got from Instruments has not changed

Tags: ios, testing, ui-automation

I am using Appium to test iOS app, but I think the problem is nothing to do with Appium.

The layout is changed by setAlpha method, our developer use it to show or hide a element(UILabel type), but the view hierarchy I got from Xcode-Instruments-Automation shows there is nothing changed in this subview.

Does anyone know how to solve this problem?
It will be better if there is a way to force Instruments to refresh the view hierarchy.

Comment: Well, if you only change the alpha, you make the element invisible to the user, but it is still there - you just can't see it. The layout engine on the other hand, can "see" it so it does take layout space. Or do you mean that it is still visible in Instruments, as if the alpha never got changed?

Comment: @Losiowaty The element in Instruments will maintain visible or invisible, it's determined by the view hierarchy I got from Instruments at the first time, which is matched the view at that time. After that, no matter how it changes in the view to the user, the element in Instruments is not changed at all.